# resubmitting a manuscript after publication cessation

Tags: fiction

*My novel "A Chase After the Wind" was published by America Star Books and sold a few copies but they never marketed the book unless I paid them to do so. I did once but it did not result in any sales*. On Feburary 7, they ended my contract
**"I am informing you that, under Par. 22 of our agreement, we are discontinuing the publication of your book A Chase After the Wind as of this day"**.

*Can I revise the manuscript, change the title and submit it to new publishers. Do I have to tell the other publishers that it was once published by America Star publishers?*

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  If you're submitting something for republication, always disclose the history of the work.  Also, make sure you review the contract you had with the original publisher to ensure you know what rights you still have, and what rights they still have.  The original publisher may still retain some rights to publish the book, even though they have discontinued publishing it for now.